# Azure Functions to login to a remote computer and perform a task

Tags: c#, azure, automation, azure-functions, .net-6.0

Is it possible to create an Azure Function that runs let's say *few times a day* that logins to a server and perform some task there?
And after it's done, it needs to give this session back to the console and disconnect.

The motivation for this is that I'd like to have a piece of code in one location (Azure Function in this case) that can monitor critical apps running in *few* of our on-prem servers.

I tried to write it but had no success, so turning to SO to see if someone else has already figured this out, so I can complete my STEPS 1 through 4 as shown below. :)

```
public static class CallRemoteComputer
{
    private const string TimerSchedule = "*/30 * * * *"; //For eg: run every 30th minute.

    [FunctionName("CallRemoteComputer")]
    public static async Task RunAsync([TimerTrigger(TimerSchedule)] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
    {
        try
        {
            string computer = "Computer_B";
            string domain = "DOMAIN";
            string username = "AdminUserName";
            string plaintextpassword = "AdminPassword";

            var securepassword = new SecureString();
            foreach (char c in plaintextpassword)
            {
                securepassword.AppendChar(c);
            }

            // STEP 1: Create Credentials and connect to this computer.
            // Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/connecting-to-wmi-remotely-with-c-
            // This computer will be running on prem.
            // So maybe it'll require something like Azure Express Route setup in this code?

            // STEP 2: Run a console app in that remote computer
            // Check if a console app I need is running, if Yes, go to next step, otherwise start the 'consoleapp.exe'.

            // STEP 3: Give this session back to the console
            // Like this but in C#:
            // https://superuser.com/a/914745

            // STEP 4: Disconnect
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.LogError(ex, $"Failed to call remote computer.");
        }
    }
}
```

References:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/connecting-to-wmi-remotely-with-c-
2. https://superuser.com/a/914745

Comment: Create a durable function with an infinite loop and use a durable timer to pause between iterations: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-timers?tabs=csharp

Comment: This feels like you're going the wrong way - dialing in - when it would be far simpler and more secure to have a service on the local machine (or modify the existing program) to upload logs or the monitoring output to Azure.  At that point normal reporting software could alert you if there wasn't a timeliness entry.  That would also make future maintenance easier, since you're not going to have to worry about things like the destination OS, or whether you also move this application to Azure, etc.

Comment: Note that if the local application is written/configured as a service, you can have it restart itself (I think most OSes impose a failed restart limit, but you likely wouldn't be able to automatically remotely start it in those situations anyways).

Comment: Side note: [`SecureString` shouldn't be used](https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0001.md)

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Thank you for the suggestion. That is solid advice. It's just that the console app that runs in the server is a third party app so we don't have any control over it to add telemetry functionality. It doesn't push logs either, so if it's down we have no idea to know it. That's why I thought maybe an Azure function checking if it's running few times a day would be a good route. One more issue is that the server sometimes restarts, and in those cases wouldn't the login done from Azure Function very helpful instead of creating Autologin in registry of each server?

Comment: Starting the program locally would be a job for something like [TaskScheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler), which is going to be relatively bulletproof - can start on boot, automatically restarts if it fails (up to a limit... or just have it start on a schedule).  Then you just write a local script that _also_ goes in the scheduler to report the status.  This means you don't have to modify firewall rules, you can use windows event reporting...

Answer (score 0):

For connecting and running tasks on on-prem you have to use the **hybrid environments with PowerShell in Azure Functions**.
You have to follow the below steps:

1. **Configure an on-premises server for PowerShell remoting**

```
# For configuration of WinRM, see
# https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/winrm/installation-and-configuration-for-windows-remote-management.

# Enable PowerShell remoting.
Enable-PSRemoting -Force

# Create firewall rule for WinRM. The default HTTPS port is 5986.
New-NetFirewallRule -Name "WinRM HTTPS" `
                    -DisplayName "WinRM HTTPS" `
                    -Enabled True `
                    -Profile "Any" `
                    -Action "Allow" `
                    -Direction "Inbound" `
                    -LocalPort 5986 `
                    -Protocol "TCP"

# Create new self-signed-certificate to be used by WinRM.
$Thumbprint = (New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName $env:COMPUTERNAME  -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My).Thumbprint

# Create WinRM HTTPS listener.
$Cmd = "winrm create winrm/config/Listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTPS @{Hostname=""$env:COMPUTERNAME ""; CertificateThumbprint=""$Thumbprint""}"
cmd.exe /C $Cmd
```

2. Create a PowerShell Function App in portal/ Locally (If you are created locally deploy it into azure and follow this step)
3. Create a hybrid connection for the function app
   Portal

- In Portal navigate to your **Azure function-> Settings -> Networking** and Select  **Configure your hybrid connections endpoints**.
- Select **Add Hybrid Connection** and add your on-prem information over there.

4. Download and install the hybrid connection

- Click the **Download connection manager** to save the ***.msi*** file local.
- Copy the  ***.msi***  file and move it into the on-premises server.
- Run the Hybrid Connection Manager installer to install the service on the on-premises server.
- From the **portal,** open the **hybrid connection** and then copy the **gateway connection string** and Open the **Hybrid Connection Manager UI** on the on-premises server. Then paste the connection string in Hybrid Connection Manager.
- **Restart** the Hybrid Connection Manager from PowerShell.( if it doesn't show as connected)

```
Restart-Service HybridConnectionManager
```

5. ***Create*** a Function and ***test*** the connection. Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-hybrid-powershell#create-a-function-http-trigger)

After add your task on function to process further.

Refer the [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-hybrid-powershell) for more information

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but your answer doesn't fully cover what's being asked in the question. Does your solution connect to on-prem server using RDP? Can you please answer the other steps (2-4) as well? 
`// STEP 2: Run a console app in that remote computer
// Check if a console app I need is running, if Yes, go to next step, otherwise start the 'consoleapp.exe'.
 // STEP 3: Give this session back to the console
 // Like this: https://superuser.com/a/914745
 // STEP 4: Disconnect`

Comment: In a above way you can try to create a **PowerShell script** to check your app is running. You can achieve all the other 3 steps using **PowerShell**.

Comment: I'd *really* like to use C# to achieve these steps because that's what me and my team are most comfortable with. :)

Comment: We can achieve this by using PowerShell. I am not sure about C# whether we can achieve or not.

Comment: Can you please post your complete solution (i.e. Steps 1 - 4) using PowerShell in your answer?